# How to format a table to display images in PHP

Tags: php, image, loops, foreach, html-table

I have images in an array and I want them to be display in a table with **3 columns**!

So obviously in HTML, it is like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="image1.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="image2.jpg"></td>
        <td><img src="image3.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</table>
```

So I want it to print out in PHP but the problem is the code.

My code is like this:

```
    $photos = array(     "image1",
                        "image2",
                        "image3",
                        "image4",
                        "image5",
            );
    foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $i = 0;
        if ($i < 3) {
            echo '<td><center><img src="'.$photo.'.jpg"></td>';
            $i++;
        } elseif ($i == 3) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $i = 0;
        }
    }
```

I don't know what seems to be the problem and every time I echo out the variable `$i`, it echoes out like 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
        $i = 0;
```

to

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($photos as $photo) {
```

Comment: Oh, I get it. Is it because when the code @ foreach loop is done? The variable $i will go back again to 0? right? therefore the $i++ will be ignore? XD

Answer (score 2):

Why is $i inside the foreach loop? That must be the reason. The $i gets initialized at the start of each loop cycle.

Comment: Just do wat Satya said and the value of $i will change.

Answer (score 2):

Try `display:inline-block;` instead in css. This works very well.

Here's an example...

```
<img src="image1.jpg" style="display:inline-block;>
<img src="image2.jpg" style="display:inline-block;>
<img src="image3.jpg" style="display:inline-block;>
```

You can even ask if you want to add text or something with the images...

Answer (score 0):

I find using array_chunk for this kind of thing is more elegant.

```
$chunks = array_chunk($photos, 3);
foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
{
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($chunk as $photo)
    {
        echo '<td><img src="', $photo, '.jpg" /></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Also, don't use the 'center' tag, it is deprecated. Use CSS to align content.

Also, strictly speaking, this is not what HTML tables are for. Sure they work well. Actually, they work better than the 'proper' solution but they are not correct. Still, go ahead and use them if you just need a quick fix. It doesn't actually cause any problem to do so.